# Команды от View в MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Например, задача отобразить диалог выбора времени. 
В MVP было бы так:

1. View говорит Presenter`у что пользователь нажал на кнопку "Выбора
   времени"
2. Presenter отправил куда то команду "Открыть диалог
   выбора времени" (допустим в Activity отправляется команда)
3. Диалог отображается (Выбираем время и выбранное время уходит в Presenter)

Как это происходит в MVVM(как правильно)?

- View само внутри открывает диалог выбора времени и отправляет выбранное значение во ViewModel?

или

- View отправляет команду во ViewModel, а там меняется какой то state на который подписано View и при смене state открывается диалог?

p.s. Все примеры паттерна MVVM построены только на отображении данных с какого то репозитория..
p.s.s. DataBinding не используется..

Comment: У меня вопрос, а чем отличается Activity от View? Первое ваше предположение верно, хочешь что-то открыть (view) делай здесь же, нужны данные - попроси VM. VM как и Presenter ничего не должны знать о View, да и андроиде в целом.

Comment: В этом отличие MVP от MVVM, в первом Presenter говорит View что делать. А тут View само решает. В вашем случае на вас как вы решите свою задачу, первым или вторым способом. Оба имеют право на жизнь, но первый из-за простоты предпочтительнее. Самому себе нет смысла слать события.

Answer (score 1):

Вся разница между ViewModel и Presenter только лишь в том, что VM нано не знает о View которые на нее подписаны. Это означает, что в целом на VM может быть подписано сколько угодно View.

Второй момент заключается в том, что зачастую мы имеем Presenter на каждую View. С VM тактика немного другая. Обычно одна VM отвечает за один тип данных или за одну категорию данных. И соответственно в каждой View может быть несколько VM.

В остальном логика взаимодействия такая же как и с Presenter. View сообщает VM от каком-то событии. VM выполняет какую-то логику и отправляет всем своим подписчикам (View) событие о полученных данных. В свою очередь View уже реагируют по своему на полученные данные. (Показывют списки, лоадеры и любую другую реакцию)